# Alloy's lone vs one quantifier on river crossing

Tags: alloy, model-checking

In the [river crossing Alloy model](http://alloytools.org/tutorials/online/frame-RC-1.html), this predicate:

```
pred crossRiver [from, from', to, to': set Object] {
  one x: from | {
    from' = from - x - Farmer - from'.eats
    to' = to + x + Farmer
  }
}
```

models the river crossing: One of the objects `x` from the `from` side moves to the `to` side, along with the Farmer.

To test my understanding, I changed: `one x: from` to `lone x: from - Farmer` --- the former moving "exactly one thing" across the river, and the latter moving "at most one non-Farmer thing".

I thought the latter better models the problem: The Farmer is hardcoded in the equality constraints and always crosses the river, and `lone` should better convey that the farmer can take zero or one things with them across the river.

However, when running the model after this change, the results are nonsense:

[image: Alloy visualization projected on State]

Here the second state instance shows the chicken and grain on both sides of the river and the farmer not having crossed at all.

What am I missing?
(This was run on Alloy 4.2_2015-02-22)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change the `one` to `lone` you allow Alloy to trivially return `true` from the `crossRiver` predicate, regardless of what the `near` and `far` look like. Therefore, the model state is *not* constrained in any way for that step. Ergo, every possible set of values for `near` and `far` in `State` is perfectly ok for Alloy.

This does not mean Alloy will somehow optimize it and never constrain. It will try for `one` (constrains properly `near` and `far`) and it will just  `true` not constraining the solution. However, both solutions must be in the solution space. Clearly there are lots more unconstrained solutions so you likely see rubbish.

If you use `one`, then Alloy **must** satisfy the predicate, which means that the body with the the `far` and `near` relations are constrained in such a way that only a valid crossing is modeled in State.

Just think of Alloy as a stone carving tool. You start with a huge block of states: every thinkable combinations of atoms in `near` and `far` and `State` are in there. However, if you skip a constraint in the trace then you get just a random combination of atoms.

A common problem where something similar is happening is:

```
  some f : Foo | no f
```

This looks like it is always false. Alas, when there are no Foo atoms this is true since the body is never looked at.

Comment: It's still constrained: `lone x` means you may not have _two_ `x`'s that satisfy the predicate.